# stiWebViewer not load on huge data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, stimulsoft

I have a very serious problem on load huge data to stiWebViewer. 
It's very very time consuming. 
I have about 40,000 records and some times I need to show all of them to use.[for export or viewing] 
but unfortunately loading data in about 1200 page is very slow. 
Is there any solution to reduce this time.

I have check render mode and in "AjaxWithCache" that all data cash in ram in the server going to next page takes 3-4 sec and load all data take about 100 sec.[I use Crystal Report with the same condition and it load data in very less time and seems good in loading huge data]

another problem is, after all data load, in page 1, I have data but in another pages There isn't any data showing.but in last pages again show data!

can you please help me to solved this problems?

Comment: What version of Stimulsoft assemblies do you use?

Comment: There is no such version and never was. What version of the Stimulsoft reports did you install?

Comment: says Stimulsoft Reports.Ultimate 2012.1 Trial, is there any solution to solve this ?

Comment: Try the latest release. It's 2014.3. There was a lot of improvements.

Comment: tanx for ur reply.. :) it does have free release ?

Comment: No, they don't have the free product